Trouble getting `xrandr -y` to reflect mouse positioning in a Lubuntu VM
I have Lubuntu 24.04 installed to a virtual machine under VMware Player 16 on a Windows 10 host.
I want to get Ubuntu's display upside-down so that it will show correctly in a glass mirror.  I have found that I can get the display itself showing correctly within a session by running xrandr -y in a terminal window in LXQt.  However, the mouse is problematic.
The mouse cursor's image is upside-down, but the movement and position of the cursor remains right-side-up: when I move the mouse upwards, the cursor moves upwards on the display, which is not correct.  When the mouse cursor is showing near the bottom of the VM's window, roll-overs appear near the top of the window (which is showing what would have been on the bottom had xrandr -y not been run).
Firstly, I don't know if xrandr -y normally also reflects the mouse cursor's positioning, since I don't have a bare metal install to try it on.  So I'm not sure if Ubuntu is doing what I want but VMware is interfering, or if Ubuntu itself is not doing what I want.
Assuming that xrandr -y acts on the frame buffer, I tried to switch to a software mouse cursor, to eliminate any possible interference by VMware.  I wasn't totally sure how to do that, but what I tried was to create a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-software-mouse.conf containing:
Section "Device"
Identifier "VMware display"
Driver "vmware"
Option "SWCursor" "true"
EndSection

The Driver "vmware" I wasn't totally sure how to determine, but I got that based on the output of sudo lsof +D /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/, which showed only one driver, /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so.
The "VMware display" is arbitrary; I read somewhere that this string is only used to reference the section in other parts of the file, so I just made something up.
Another thing I thought to try is to adjust how VMware handles the hardware cursor.  I don't know how it does so.  In principle when the VM guest tweaks the registers that set the hardware overlay's position, VMware should use that to reposition the cursor on the host, but perhaps it doesn't actually do that.
So, I tried adding a setting in VMware Player's preferences.ini:
pref.motionUngrab = "FALSE"

This causes the VM to trap the mouse, such that it doesn't leave the VM's window until pressing [Ctrl]+[Alt] to release it.  However, the mouse's positioning remains incorrect: moving the mouse upwards moves the cursor upwards, whereas it should be moving downwards.
I don't know if there are any other VMware settings I should look at; there's nothing obvious I can see in the Player GUI, the preferences.ini file, or the *.vmx file.
To be clear, what should happen is that when the guest is given focus, the host's mouse cursor should jump from the top of the window to the bottom of the window, or vice-versa.  But that does not happen.
Thinking VMware Tools might be interfering by implementing well-meaning "magic" that doesn't account for the reflected display, I've tried all this on a fresh VM that has never had open-vm-tools or open-vm-tools-desktop installed, but it does the same thing.
Putting the VM in full screen mode does not help.  (That mode doesn't give the guest direct access to the video hardware anyway, it just hides the host's GUI.)
I realize the hardware cursor positioning issue may (or may not) be outside the scope of Ubuntu, but in principle it should be possible to make the guest (Ubuntu) draw the mouse cursor into the frame buffer itself, so that at very worst, I'll have two cursors: the host cursor in the wrong place, but the guest cursor in the right place, which would be not great but tolerable.
But it's obvious that Ubuntu either (i) ignored my (perhaps incorrect) attempt to use a software cursor, or (ii) implements the software cursor in a way that bypasses whatever xrandr -y does.
What else can I try?

I have about 10 different Linux VMs running with VBox - no such Problem, neither with KDE nor with LXQT. It looks like a VMWare glitch. Maybe you could try to install VirtualBox and run Lubuntu - just to verify

@kanehekili Thanks for the suggestion!  Tried the same image in VirtualBox.. by default it screws up in the same way Player does, but by switching off Mouse Integration, it works as expected.  VirtualBox seems overall more configurable.
